# iTextSharp validate pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfa

For my internship, I need to verify a signed PFD/A file to guarantee that the client will receive the official document.
Now I've created a signed PDF/A file with iTextSharp. When I open this file in Adobe Reader it shows me that there is a signature present.

Now I need to verify the file in the code before I can send it to the clients, but when I try to verify it using the `GetSignatureNames` function or the `GetBlankSignatures` function, it keeps returning that there are no signature names.

I'm using the following code to verify:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(cdr.PDFAkteNaam);
AcroFields af = reader.AcroFields;
var names = af.GetSignatureNames();
if (names.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error","No Signature Present in PDF file.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Succes!", "Success!");
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the signed test-file we got from notaryship. It contains fictional data just for testing. [Link to file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26016583/8%20K%C3%A4ster%20-testakte%20goed%20PDF-A.pdf)

Comment: Please provide a sample file. Checking the number of signature names should be the way to go.

Comment: Works for me for the PDF you provided.  It prints "Success!".  If I print the field names returned by `GetSignatureNames()`, I see 1 field called "Signature2".

Comment: Which iTextSharp version do you use? Certain old (well, ancient) version did not find all AcroForm signature fields.

Comment: Hmm, strange. We're using version 5.4.1.

Comment: Tested with 5.4.1: also works.  Are you sure you are reading the correct PDF file?

Comment: Thanks @rhens. Apparently when the PDF file is loaded, the software moves the document to a secure folder somewhere on a user defined location. The signature is still present in the document, but now it is selectable as text and not a valid signature anymore. Thank you for the help.